# Spring Webflow with Primefaces

Tags: spring, jsf, primefaces, spring-webflow

We have an application which is developed using Spring Webflow and there are some new requirements for which we are planning to use Primefaces because we have used it in other projects.  This application already have screens developed in JSP and we are thinking to develop new screens as XHTML pages for primefaces. My question is can we use both jsp and xhtml with webflow ? If yes, does anyone has a working sample.

Thanks
-Raj

Comment: Take a look at this: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-webflow-samples/tree/master/primefaces-showcase

Comment: The sample is for using xhtml with webflow, that part is working for us. I am trying to see mix of JSP and XHTML can work with webflow.